error al subir una imagen a aws s3, solo me deja subir archivos txt pero imagenes jpg no, que estoy haciendo mal?
Como mencione al principio cuando subo un archivo txt si sube a s3 y se puede visulizar con normalidad pero al momento de subir un pdf o una imagen como jpg se cae el postman -> POST http://localhost:3000/dev/documento/upload
Error: read ECONNRESET
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.37.0
Accept: /
Postman-Token: 39c1ea5a-d91e-411e-b4e8-902802789b16
Host: localhost:3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Request Body
file: undefined
o con otros intentos me sale este error
" statusCode: 500 .
"message": "Internal server error"
s3.service.ts
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  S3Client,
  PutObjectCommand,
  ObjectCannedACL,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

import { Express } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class S3Service {
  private logger = new Logger(S3Service.name);
  private region: string;
  private s3: S3Client;

  constructor() {
    this.region = process.env.AWS_REGION;
    this.s3 = new S3Client({
      region: this.region,
    });
  }

  async uploadImage(file: Express.Multer.File): Promise<string> {
    const bucketName = process.env.BUCKET1;
    const key = `${uuidv4()}-${file.originalname}`;

    const input = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: key,
      Body: file.buffer,
      ContentType: file.mimetype,
      ACL: 'public-read' as ObjectCannedACL,
    };

    try {
      await this.s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(input));
      const url = `https://${bucketName}.s3.${this.region}.amazonaws.com/${key}`;
      return url;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error('Error uploading image to S3:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

documento.repository.ts
import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MysqConfig } from '../../_config/mysqlConnect';
import serverlessMysql from 'serverless-mysql';

import { S3Service } from './s3.service';
import { AgregarDocumentoRequest } from './data/request';
import { AgregarDocumentoResponse } from './data/response';

@Injectable()
export class DocumentoRepository {
  private conn: serverlessMysql.ServerlessMysql;

  constructor(
    private readonly mySql: MysqConfig,
    private readonly s3Service: S3Service,
  ) {
    this.conn = this.mySql.conn();
  }

  async uploadImage(file: Express.Multer.File): Promise<string> {
    return this.s3Service.uploadImage(file);
  }
}

documento.service.ts
import { Injectable, InternalServerErrorException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DocumentoRepository } from './documento.repository';
import { AgregarDocumentoRequest } from './data/request';
import { AgregarDocumentoResponse } from './data/response';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { Builder } from 'builder-pattern';
import { ObjectResponse } from '../commons/data/response';
import { metaDataSucees } from '../../utils';

@Injectable()
export class DocumentoService {
  constructor(private readonly documentoRepository: DocumentoRepository) {}

  async uploadImage(file: Express.Multer.File): Promise<string> {
    return this.documentoRepository.uploadImage(file);
  }
}


documento.controller.ts
import {
  Controller,
  Delete,
  Get,
  Headers,
  Param,
  Patch,
  Post,
  Body,
  UploadedFile,
  UseInterceptors,
  InternalServerErrorException,
  UploadedFiles,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ObjectResponse } from '../commons/data/response';
import { FileInterceptor, FilesInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { DocumentoService } from './documento.service';
import {
  AgregarDocumentoRequest,
  ActualizarDocumentoRequest,
  TipoDocumentoRequest,
} from './data/request';
import {
  AgregarDocumentoResponse,
  TipoDocumentoResponse,
} from './data/response';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

@Controller('documento')
export class DocumentoController {
  constructor(private readonly documentoService: DocumentoService) {}

  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  async uploadImage(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
  ): Promise<string> {
    return this.documentoService.uploadImage(file);
  }
}


